# Search query with sql and json

Tags: php, sql, json

My Problem is i get all data for my website in json format, so i have also a section with checkboxes for search (using **php**), i don't have any idea, how can i develop now this filter, exactly is my problem how to create sql requst for selected checkboxes? In the backoffice of my website i select values via selectbox, but that don't have influence on my *json code*.

If i decode json code so:

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

That's what i mean is:

```
SELECT * FROM content_attributes WHERE = 'my_json_value'
```

It's the right way?

Comment: Please explain your problem in a clearer way I and maybe other dont get the problem at all.

Comment: 1. All website data is in json format
2. Needed is a search form
3. Checkboxes for search form are also from json
4. How can i create here a search query, if i select a few checkboxes, how can i filter it, i don't konow because i don't have experience with json.
5. My idea was some query like this: SELECT * FROM content_attributes WHERE = 'my_json_value'

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the column name after the `where` keyword like this

```
SELECT * FROM content_attributes WHERE column_name = 'my_json_value'
```

Comment: I try to explain so:

SELECT * FROM content_attributes WHERE id = 7

The rows of this tables are:
id->row id | name->name is only for frontend | value->here are json values what i need, thats my problem, how can i select value, this i can edit in backoffice... but i need values also for frontend search